# calculating many dask delayed objects together; message as soon as each is finished?

Tags: python, dask

I have a number of dask delayed objects that I am computing together, resulting in files being written to disk, such as in this toy example:

```
import xarray as xr
import dask.array as da

objs = []
for i in range(10):
    ds = xr.Dataset({"x": (("a",), da.arange(10)*i)})
    objs.append(ds.to_netcdf(f"/tmp/test{i:d}.nc", compute=False))
da.compute(objs)
```

Is there a way to execute some arbitrary code for each individual delayed object, as soon as computation has completed successfully?

Motivation: in our real case, we are producing in the order of 100 files that may take between 10 seconds and 8 minutes to produce.  We would like to ship each file to the user as soon as possible.  Alternatives we considered:

- We could use inotify to monitor the directory for `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` events.  This is not ideal, because it can't tell if writing was successful or not, so we would need another step to check if the file appears correct.
- We could wait until `da.compute` is complete and then ship all files.  This is our current approach, but it is not ideal, because then we are waiting for the 8-minute-product to complete before shipping all products at once, leading to a needless wait and a jam in the network and the client application.
- Ideally, dask would send a message or execute a piece of code for each completed task, so that we can ship each file to the user as soon as it is completed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Maybe we could wrap everything in a `dask.delayed` function that has the `to_netcdf` call and the callback?  But considering my poor understanding of dask, I'm not sure what repercussions that might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to have a second delayed function which depends on the output of the to_netcdf objects

```
@dask.delayed
def on_done(result):
    notify(from(result)

objs2 = [on_done(_) for _ in objs]
dask.compute(objs2)
```

The `result` will be whatever type `to_netcdf` returns - hopefully the filename created.

Comment: Should that be `return notify(from_(result))`?

Comment: That depends on whether your notify function returns anything, but sure! I had assumed it was a side-effect only function.

Comment: If we don't return, `dask.compute(objs2)` will be just passed a list of `None`, won't it?

Comment: It would evaluate to a list of None when complete

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when the `delayed` object I'm wrapping is coming from `da.store(sources, targets, delayed=False)`; when `on_done` is called, the output file still has size 0.

Comment: You mean `compute=False`?

Comment: Yes, I mean `compute=False`.  But it may be something the target class is doing, I don't understand this nearly well enough yet and am trying to pin down to where the difference lies.

Comment: Ah, the problem in the `da.store(sources, targets, delayed=False)` case is that a finished computation does not mean the data have been flushed to disk.  So the computation is finished, but if targets is (for example) a hdf5 object, it doesn't show up for the file yet (see a MCVE in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/pytroll/trollflow2/pull/168#issuecomment-1311508838) if you're interested).